# JavaScript only allow letter space and number

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form where I want to validate the **buyer** input filed using JavaScript.

I want if the user does not write **letter or space or number** then will show an alert. Basically, I want to accept the only letter, space and number.

For that, I am using this JS function with validation rules for the buyer field. But seems like it's wrong :(

```
function validateForm () {

    var amount      =   document.forms["salesform"]["amount"];               
    var buyer       =   document.forms["salesform"]["buyer"];    
    var receipt_id  =   document.forms["salesform"]["receipt_id"];  
    var buyer_email =   document.forms["salesform"]["buyer_email"];  
    var note        =   document.forms["salesform"]["note"];  
    var city        =   document.forms["salesform"]["city"];  
    var phone       =   document.forms["salesform"]["phone"];
    var entry_by    =   document.forms["salesform"]["entry_by"];      
    var buyerRegex  =   "/^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/" 


    if (amount.value == "") { 
        alert("Please enter the amount."); 
        amount.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } else if (isNaN(amount.value)) {
        alert("Amount should be only numeric value."); 
        amount.focus(); 
        return false; 
    }

    if (buyer.value == "") { 
        alert("Buyer name is required"); 
        buyer.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } else if (!buyer.value.match(buyerRegex)) {
        alert("Buyer name only contain letter, number and space."); 
        buyer.focus(); 
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "I want to accept the only letter, space and number." is a vague requirement. How about a string with 100 spaces and nothing more?

Comment: @georg looks like it must start with a letter : `var buyerRegex = "/^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/"`

Comment: @Cid: ok, a letter and 99 spaces then ;)

Comment: @georg seems to be a legit name :D

Comment: But looks like `O'Connor` is not a valid name.

Comment: One space between a word. So it could be like this: Alex1 Mojum or 1 Mojum Alex etc

Comment: `André Citroën` is not a valid name ?

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."*

Comment: Is this okay for this name: Alex Mojum 1? `var buyerRegex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;  alert(buyerRegex.test(buyer.value));`

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you use 0-9 in place of a-z?

```
var buyerRegex  =   "/^[a-z0-9\s]*$/"
```

Answer (score -1):

insted of match try to use test for regix

```
buyerRegex = "/^[a-z0-9\s]*$/"

if (!buyer.value.test(buyerRegex)) {
        alert("Buyer name only contain letter, number and space."); 
        buyer.focus(); 
        return false; 
    }
```